# theoretic possibility of building hardware exactly equal to any software

Tags: finite-automata

Is it possible in theory to build hardware with exactly same computing logic as any computer program? Or in other words: Is it possible in theory to implement any software in hardware?

That's my thoughts: if computers in general is finite automata so the software what is a product of computer is in general finite automata. So there is no principal difference beetween them. That's mean it is possible.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible or not?
2. If it is possible, am I correct with explanation?

Comment: Just build a piece of hardware that is a current computer with the particular program hardcoded in; and that *is* an implementation in hardware.  (If it doesn't feel like one to you, I challenge you to come up with a precise definition of what you would accept as hardware.)

Comment: Under hardware i mean composition of CPU, RAM, motherboard and peripheral. In other words "something" before Boot OS. 
I think BIOS is the part of hardware. But architecture in target theoretical device might be another.